# How to execute a .NET Core console application on startup as a (daemon) service for the raspberry pi

Tags: c#, .net-core, raspberry-pi, console-application, daemon

I would like to know how i can run a dotnet console application as a service on a raspberry pi.

I can start the application mannualy by typing '''./dotnet/garagedeur_pi/publish/Garagedeur'''

I've created a Garagedeur.Service file:

```
Description=Garagedeur

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/dotnet/garagedeur_pi/publish/Garagedeur.dll
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/dotnet/garagedeur/pi/publish
#Restart=always
#RestartSec=10
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I check the status I get this:

```
● Garagedeur.service - Garagedeur
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/Garagedeur.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-02-17 12:09:49 CET; 11min ago
  Process: 1142 ExecStart=/home/pi/dotnet/garagedeur_pi/publish/Garagedeur.dll (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
 Main PID: 1142 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)

Feb 17 12:09:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Garagedeur.
Feb 17 12:09:49 raspberrypi systemd[1142]: Garagedeur.service: Changing to the requested working directory failed: No such file or directory
Feb 17 12:09:49 raspberrypi systemd[1142]: Garagedeur.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /home/pi/dotnet/garagedeur_pi/publish/Garagedeur.dll: No such file or directory
Feb 17 12:09:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Garagedeur.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Feb 17 12:09:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Garagedeur.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Solution:

> Just read the error message and see that garagedeur/pi/ is different from garagedeur_pi/. Also there is a difference between Garagedeur.dll and Garagedeur – M. Spiller Feb 17 at 11:33

Comment: The error message is quite clear, systemd cannot start your service because (1) it cannot change to the working directory specified because it does not exist and (2) it cannot execute the Garagedeur.dll because it does not exist at the given path. Make sure your paths are correct, and your .NET Core application is published for Linux ARM 32 bit (maybe think about making it self contained so your PI doesn't need dotnet installed. If you do this, don't forget to make your file executable by doing `sudo chmod +x`)

Comment: Just read the error message and see that `garagedeur/pi/` is different from `garagedeur_pi/`. Also there is a difference between `Garagedeur.dll` and `Garagedeur`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look here how to create the service file [Host ASP.NET on Linux with Nginx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-5.0).
In your service file you have to add the location of .NET installation, like this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/pi/dotnet/garagedeur_pi/publish/Garagedeur.dll
```

Here a example:

```
[Unit]
Description=Garagedeur

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/pi/dotnet/garagedeur_pi/publish/Garagedeur.dll
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/dotnet/garagedeur/pi/publish
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The path `/usr/bin/dotnet` is depending were you have installed .NET. On my raspberry pi this path is `/home/pi/dotnet-arm32/dotnet`. You can finde the right path with the command

> dotnet --info